# .NET programs don't run at logon screen - windows 7

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-screensaver

I'm using Windows 7 Pro (32bit) and have .NET 3.5 and 4 installed...

I have written a .NET screensaver and have enabled it to run on the Windows logon screen.

My problem is that it errors:

> .NET framework initialisation error

BUT when I'm logged in the screensaver works...

So it isn't a faulty installation of the .NET framework, or else it wouldn't work fullstop.

Any ideas?

Comment: He wants the screensaver to be able to initalise before he logs into his account

Comment: i'd bet this is a security risk, so windows doesn't allow it.

Comment: No user is logged attached to the desktop when logon screen shows so I'd bet that this alone is enough to make .net framework fail to initialise.

Comment: Maybe take a look at GINA - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @ricky GINA? That hasn't existed since Vista. Why do people still think GINA exists?

Comment: What is your screensaver doing? Direct3D support is not enabled on the login screen so if you require this then that would explain the error.

Comment: Seems like it _is_ possible: [Logon Screen Launcher](https://logonscreenlauncher.codeplex.com/). I haven't tried it, so I haven't put this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible on login screen. The core services needed to be able to run a windows program(.Net or not) have not yet been loaded/initialized.

Unless your trying to develop a program outside of windows' jurisdiction (such as bootable, console programs)